# WebView implementation with Firebase Database in Android

Tags: android, url, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

I want to implement **webView** with **Firebase** so that if I add a **URL** in **firebase Database** it gets implemented on my webView **in application** in **realtime**, I have successfully implemented the text and images through database but could not get webView work correctly, I have searched many options but neither work for me, please help. If you want any more detail I can provide you.

> I am using Android Studio

**Below is my Java class code for Firebase implementation for Images and text**

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            sentToStart();
        }
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

            post.class,
            R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
            postViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setdescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setsource(model.getSource());
        }
    };
    mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.title_cardView);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setsource(String source){
        TextView post_source = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.source_cardView);
        post_source.setText(source);
    }

    public void setdescription(String description){
        TextView post_description = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.description_cardView);
        post_description.setText(description);
    }

    public void setimage(final Context ctx, final String image){
        final ImageView post_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Getter/Setter Java Class**

```
public class post {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private String source;



    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public post(){
    }

    public post(String title, String description, String image, String source) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**Updated: WebView java Activity**

```
public class webViewNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webviewthis;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mdataRef;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("webView");
        webviewthis = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);


        mdataRef.child("webView").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.child("webView").getValue();
                    webviewthis.loadUrl("");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you've tried in the WebView itself.

Comment: Can you share us the WebView?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sure i will edit up in my question

Comment: @DougStevenson i will edit up in my question

Comment: @DougStevenson  As I dont know what to do more than this with webView can you please help me, i am being stuck here for few days

Comment: @AlexMamo  As I dont know what to do more than this with webView can you please help me, i am being stuck here for few days

Comment: You haven't loaded any content at all in the WebView yet.  What exactly are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @DougStevenson sir i was trying webView.loadUrl() in the onDataChange but didnt get anything from it, can you please help me here and tell me how to do it, i am not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as i see in your code, you are using `.child("webView")` twice. Once in the `DatabaseReference` and once when you add the `ValueEventListener`. Is that what you are having in your database? If there are no duplicate childrens in your database, you need to remove one of them.

You have added a `ValueEventListener` on `mdataRef` but you are doing nothing there. Your `onDataChange()` method is empty. Remember, this method is triggered every time a change is taking place in your database. So in order to display some content, you need to get the data out from the `dataSnapshot` object according to your database structure and display it right there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply sir, please can you tell me what to write inside the onDataChange( ) method, as i was previously implementing the webView and was getting errors with it. Thanks in advance sir

Comment: Please update your answer with what is in `onDataChange()` that does not work.

Comment: i was implementing like this sir

 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.child("webView").getValue();
                    webviewthis.loadUrl("");
                }

Comment: done sir, please tell me how to get URL from firebase Database to webView

Comment: yes sir solved, but can you please look into this matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093182/adding-youtube-api-with-recyclerview-using-firebase-in-android?noredirect=1#comment79148964_46093182

Comment: Ok, i will take a look and if can help you, i'll give you an answer.