# Adding Youtube API with RecyclerView using Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, youtube-api, android-cardview

I am building an application in which I want to use **Youtube API** for running videos but the problem is that the youtube API is copied to all **card** items where I dont want it to come, I only want a specific post where the video can be played and not on all posts. I am also using **RecyclerView** and **cardView** in this application with **Firebase** as my database.please help me reduce this **redundancy problem**, I have researched many questions but did not found anything useful. Is there any way by which the video can only be played on some post of cardView and not on all. for example **facebook** application or **instagram** application where videos come on specific posts and not on all.

> I am using Android Studio

**Youtube FirebaseAdapter class file:**

```
  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

        post.class,
        R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
        postViewHolder.class,
        mDatabaseReference
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setYoutube(model.getYoutube());
    }
};
mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

View mView;

public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}
public void setYoutube(final String youtube){
    final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
    youPlay.initialize("SOME KEY",
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtube);
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
}
```

**youtube CardView xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtuber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Comment: Create different view types and initialise the view type based on the type of item expected to appear. For example,two view types: image type & video type which can be added based on the requirement

Comment: @GautamiBhandary yes, but how to initialise different views, this is what i want to know

Comment: You can create different view type by creating different view holders for the layout files and you can use common view data binders as a single view type

Comment: @GautamiBhandary can you please refer me to some link example or code snippet.